# Clipboard.SetText with large amount of text fails with no error .NET

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I'm trying to use `Clipboard.SetText()` to allow the user of my application to copy certain items into the clipboard. It is very possible that the user could attempt to copy a very large amount of text to the clipboard (130 MB+). I've tried this a few times, and when I then go to paste the text into another program nothing comes out. I don't get any kind of indication/exception in `SetText()` that the operation failed. Is there a way to detect this without actually reading back from the clipboard and performing a comparison? Or perhaps is there a hard limit I can enforce on my end to throw an error message before sending it to `SetText()`?

Much thanks.

Comment: Is the clipboard empty after copying or maybe the program you try to paste into doesn't support it?

Comment: I can't be sure, but I tried pasting into Notepad, Notepad++ and some other text editors and nothing happens.

Comment: Well that's not likely then. The limit of the size of text the clipboard can accept is the free (virtual) memory, so you could check that. Another issue may be that there's a null char at the start of the text (char value 0). That would flag the clipboard that the end of the content was reached and no further data follows.